# Como ocultar información del servidor a Wappalyzer

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Ayer me dispuse a mejorar la seguridad de mis servidores y encontré que mi versión de apache2, PHP e incluso mi sistema operativo se podían obtener de forma sencilla con el plugin de chrome Wappalyzer. Me estuve informando para ocultar la información y llegue a un par de lineas de configuración en el archivo `apache.conf`, `ServerTokens Prod` y `ServerSignature Off`, con esto conseguí eliminar la versión de Apache pero sigue saliendo que estoy usando esa tecnología. En PHP me sucede algo similar y no es lo que quiero, yo quiero ocultar todo información.
Quizá en este punto pienses que es imposible pero si que se puede, páginas Web como `google.com` no muestra ninguna información de sus servidores y me gustaría conseguir lo mismo. 
Os adjunto una captura de pantalla de como se ve el plugin al intentar escanear la web de `google.com` y así es como me gustaría que se viera el mio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por adelantado.